# show and Hide loading with Ajax / PHP

Tags: php, ajax, loader

I try to do something basic but i block.

I want to add a class to a div for loading when i click on "GO" and remove the class when i get the answer.

My code is :

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "/send_email",
          type: "POST",
          data: $('form').serialize(),
          beforeSend: function() {
           $('div.loading').classList.add('d-block');
          },
          })
          .done(function(response) {
            $('div.loading').classList.remove('d-block')
            $('div.message').html(response);
          });   
      return false;
  };
```

The HTML is :

```
<div class="loading">Loading</div>
```

What im doig wrong ?

Actualy the page reload and in the console i get:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

i try to find my div seperatly and i get it !

I want to show and hide the loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up jQuery code and non-jQuery code.  You can use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead:

```
$('div.loading').toggleClass('d-block');
```

`classList` is part of [the element itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), not the jQuery object.  Which you *can* access from jQuery:

```
$('div.loading').get(0).classList.add('d-block');
```

But it doesn't make much sense to do so.  Since you're already using jQuery, you might as well remain consistent with that.

---

> Actualy the page reload

That sounds like a separate problem entirely, and one that exists outside of the code shown.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission) may be helpful, but all we can do is guess since the code shown doesn't demonstrate this specific problem.

Comment: You got it in few minute !  I didn't realize that, Bravo and thank you.